# How do you do pairwise muliplication?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

So I am really new at coding (JAVA) and I need to do a pairwise multiplication.
as an example, consider the list [ 2, 5, 6]
the list returned should be [10, 12, 30]

So how do I make sure that they only multiplicate with the other numbers and not with themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, then it seems that you want to use a `for-loop`, and you're trying to get the product of all elements in an array except the current element.

If this is the case, then you example should be:

```
[2, 5, 6] => [30, 12, 10]
```

Here's my solution:

```
public int[] pairWise(int[] numbers) {
    int[] res = new int[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int[] temp = new int[numbers.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, temp, 0, i);
        System.arraycopy(numbers, i + 1, temp, i, numbers.length - i - 1);
        int product = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
            product *= temp[j];
        }
        res[i] = product;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This solution is pretty ineffective, since it uses 2 `for-loops`, which makes it **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

Comment: this has been a great help, thankyou, I just got one more question. I need to be able to do it in this format:                                                                                                                              public static void main(String[] args) {                                                  and                                                                                      public static int[] getPairwiseMultiplications(List<Integer> numbers) {                                                            would you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: I don't understand how this code could work if your input has a `length >=4.`

Comment: @justTrying You can use `numbers..stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();` to convert the ArrayList to an Array. If this doesn't work, then you can create an array using 
`intArray = new int[numbers.size()];`, and loop through the ArrayList, and assign each value in the ArrayList to the Array. I barely know Java so sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lrrr Not sure what you mean. I just tested my code with an array that has an length of 7.

`{2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4, 9} => {2160, 864, 720, 2160, 4320, 1080, 480}`

Comment: The result of pair wise multiplication of list of 7 elements should have 21 elements not 7!

Comment: @Lrrr It's possible that we're thinking of different things. The algorithm that I wrote gets the product off all values in an array except for the current value. If you had read my entire answer, then you would know this. Next time you should read the entire answer.

Comment: The op asked for **pairwise multiplication**. You could sure does something! Every algorithm does something. But it is not the answer to this question.

Comment: @Lrrr They also said this:
"So how do I make sure that they **only multiplicate with the other numbers and not with themselves?**"
This is what I coded. So they asked for both things and I provided one. So my solution was an answer to the question. Also, why would they mark it as an answer if it wasn't what they wanted.